# "http" directive is not allowed here Nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I start and I want to connect to my database with Nginx. Here is my `sites-enables / default` file:

```
http {
  upstream database {
   postgres_server 192.168.0.166 dbname=stardb 
                                user=username password=yourpass;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location /ip {
      postgres_pass     database;

      postgres_query    HEAD GET  "SELECT http_host as ip FROM establishment_view where aet = 'NXS_DEV_FLO2'";
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> nginx[7597]: nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:17

I saw that this error was common but even looking at the other posts I can not solve my problem.
And I have this line in my `nginx.conf` file :

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Did I need to remove the line http in my `sites_enables/default` file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do include it is as good as pasting the content from the matching files. So if my main `nginx.conf` is

```
http {
   line 1
   line 2;
   include sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

And `sites-enabled/default.conf` is below

```
http {
   server { 
      line 3;
   }
}
```

The effective config becomes

```
http {
   line 1;
   line 2;
   http {
      server {
          line 3; 
      }
   }
}
```

Now `http` directive is not allowed inside any other directive, you can use it at root level. So the error that `"http" directive is not allowed here`. You should run `nginx -T` to see full combine config that it uses.

The fix is simple, remove the `http` enclosing block from `default` file, as you already are inside a `http` block

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I remove `http` of `sites-enabled`. Now I have this error : `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "postgres_server" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:20
`

Comment: You need to compile nginx with the add-on plugin I assume https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_postgres

Comment: Do you know how I can add this module ? Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: Look at this https://openresty.org/en/components.html. Then build with postgres module included

Comment: Thanks I will try this.